# substracting days with Calendar does not decrement year?

Tags: java, date, calendar

in order to thank me an happy new year, my java code is making something really unexpected : It does not decrement year when substracting 11 days at current date of 06/01/2022.

Somebody knows why it does not return "2021-12-26" ???

Code :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat('YYYY-MM-dd');
Date dt = new Date();
println "current_date : " + dateFormat.format(dt);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dt);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -11);
dt = c.getTime();
println "substracted_date : " + dateFormat.format(dt);
```

Console :

```
current_date : 2022-01-06
substracted_date : 2022-12-26
```

Comment: You are using an API that is outdated for reasons. One of them is behaviour as described in your question. You can have that easier with `java.time`. By the way, your code is actually working on my machine, it does decrement the year: *substracted_date : 2021-12-26*. Have you tried lower-case year, like `"yyyy-MM-dd"`?

Comment: well seen deHaar
wrong pattern YYYY was the cause

Comment: Yes, using a modern library would not have changed much when the `String` pattern is the cause of the error. It is still recommended to use `java.time`, consider it. The calculation would just be `LocalDate.now().minusDays(11)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date format `YYYY` is the pattern for week year, instead of `yyyy` is for year.

The week year is updated by the week. For example, 2021-12-26 is the start of the first week of 2022 instead of 2021, so it'll show 2022. But the year is updated by date, so it'll show 2021.

Therefore, just change `YYYY` to `yyyy` and it'll work fine.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Wow, not easy to understand how it works to calculate 2022, but now it works ^^ ; it is not the first time I get strange behavior because I does not use good pattern case. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Try using LocalDate from Java8

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2022-01-06");
        System.out.println("Date : "+date);

        LocalDate newDate = date.minusDays(11);
        System.out.println("New Date : "+newDate);
    }
}
```

This will give you output as below
**Date : 2022-01-06
New Date : 2021-12-26**

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Nekomura

to not be annoyed next time, I took belt and braces with 2 assert in order to not been surprised if using wrong pattern ^^ :

```
/**
 * renvoie un timestamp Fr de la date du serveur
 * @param pattern (du type "dd-MM-yyyy" ou "HH:mm:ss")
 * @param day_to_add permet d'ajout/retrancher des jours à la date actuelle
 * @param hour_to_add permet d'ajout/retrancher des heures à la date actuelle
 * @return le timetstamp au format correspondant à @pattern
 */
@Keyword
public static String getServerTimestamp(String pattern, int day_to_add, int hour_to_add) {

    assert !pattern.contains("Y") : "ne pas utiliser pattern 'Y' mais 'y' (sinon on prend week year et ça marche pas bien) ; voir reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html"
    assert !pattern.contains("D") : "ne pas utiliser pattern 'D' mais 'd' (sinon on prend day in year et ça marche pas bien) ; voir reference https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html"
    
    Date dt = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(dt);
    if (day_to_add != null) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, day_to_add);
    }
    if (hour_to_add != null) {
        c.add(Calendar.HOUR, hour_to_add);
    }
    dt = c.getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    return dateFormat.format(dt);
}
```